# Itunesartwork glosseffect

Tags: ios, itunes, effect, itunesartwork, gloss

I have a problem with displaying `ITunesArtwork` icon gloss effect through https://itunes.apple.com/app/id738696013
Gloss effect you may view despite the fact that had set option "iOS icon is pre-rendered display" at YES.

If you view the application via `iTunes` or via `AppStore` on the tablet with `iOS6` version - everything is OK, no gloss effect. 
The problem climbs only when viewing application for instructions above app.

I use `Xcode` version 5.0.2 (5A3005).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nothing, the _iTunes_ application show your icon properly without the gloss effect. your updated your app a day ago only and you need to know the icons, keyword registration in search engine will be updated in next 24-48 hours.